# Flask-Rest-API only returns 1 attribute when returning JSON

Tags: python, flask

I am developing an API that uses Flask, `flask_sqlalchemy`, `flask_marshmallow`, and `flask_restful` to serialize and store data in the db.

I have about 15 Models and all of them work for except for this one:

```
class Student(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'student'

studentId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
name = db.Column(db.String(50))
email = db.Column(db.String(50))
courses = db.relationship("StudentCourses")
connected = db.Column(db.Boolean)

def __repr__(self):
    return "Student Id : {}, Name: {}, Email: {}, Courses: {}, Connected: {}".format(self.studentId, self.name, self.email, self.courses, self.connected)

# Marshmellow Schema
class StudentSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("studentId", "name", "email", "courses", "connected")

# Schema for Multiple Students
students_schema = StudentSchema(many = True)

# Schema for Individual Students
student_schema = StudentSchema()

class StudentListResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        posts = Student.query.all()
        # the posts are stored in the database but it only returns the name 
        for i in posts:
            print(i)
        return students_schema.dump(posts)

    def post(self):
        connection = False

        if request.json['connected'] == "True" or request.json['connected'] == 'true':
            connection = True
        
        newStudent = Student(
            name = request.json['name'],
            email = request.json['email'],
            connected = connection
        )

        db.session.add(newStudent)
        db.session.commit()
        return student_schema.dump(newStudent)


class StudentResource(Resource):

    def get(self, studentId):
        student = Student.query.get_or_404(studentId)
        return student_schema.dump(student)

    def patch(self, studentId):
        student = Student.query.get_or_404(studentId)

        if 'studentId' in request.json:
            student.studentId = request.json['studentId']

        if 'name' in request.json:
            student.name = request.json['name']

        if 'email' in request.json:
            student.email = request.json['email']

        if 'connected' in request.json and (request.json['connected'] == 'True' or request.json['connected'] == 'true'):
            student.connected = True

        db.session.commit()
        return student_schema.dump(student)

    
    def delete(self, studentId):
        student = studentId.query.get_or_404(studentId)
        db.session.delete(student)
        db.session.commit()
        return '', 204
    
# Registering the Endpoints 
api.add_resource(StudentListResource, '/students')
api.add_resource(StudentResource, '/students/<int:studentId>')
```

When running an insertion using:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/students \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"name":"dean", "email":"test@dean.com", "connected":"True"}
```

It inserts the whole row but only returns the name field:

```
 {
        "name": "dean"
 }
```

The correct output should look like this:

```
{
   "studentId": "1", "name": "dean", "email": "test@dean.com", "connected":"true"
}
```

I am not sure why this is the case because I have a nearly identical schema called Teacher that returns and inserts the whole row correctly. It looks like this:

```
# TEACHER
class Teacher(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'

    teacherId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    courses = db.relationship("TeacherCourses")
    connected = db.Column(db.Boolean)


    def __repr__(self):

        return "Teacher Id : {}, Name: {}, Email: {}, Courses: {}, Connected: {}".format(self.teacherId, self.name, self.email, self.courses, self.connected)


# Marshmellow Schema
class TeacherSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:

        fields = ("teacherId", "name", "email", "courses", "connected")

# Schema for Multiple Teachers
teachers_schema = TeacherSchema(many = True)


# Schema for Individual Teachers
teacher_schema = TeacherSchema()

class TeacherListResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        posts = Teacher.query.all()
        return teacher_schema.dump(posts)

    def post(self):
        connection = False

        if request.json['connected'] == "True" or request.json['connected'] == 'true':
            connection = True
        
        newTeacher = Teacher(
            name = request.json['name'],
            email = request.json['email'],
            connected = connection
        )

        db.session.add(newTeacher)
        db.session.commit()
        return teacher_schema.dump(newTeacher)


class TeacherResource(Resource):

    def get(self, teacherId):

        teacher = Teacher.query.get_or_404(teacherId)
        return teacher_schema.dump(teacher)

    def patch(self, teacherId):

        teacher = Teacher.query.get_or_404(teacherId)

        if 'teacherId' in request.json:
            teacher.teacherId = request.json['teacherId']

        if 'name' in request.json:
            teacher.name = request.json['name']

        if 'email' in request.json:
            teacher.email = request.json['email']

        if 'connected' in request.json and (request.json['connected'] == 'True' or request.json['connected'] == 'true'):
            teacher.connected = True

        db.session.commit()
        return teacher_schema.dump(teacher)

    
    def delete(self, teacherId):

        teacher = teacherId.query.get_or_404(teacherId)
        db.session.delete(teacher)
        db.session.commit()
        return '', 204
    
# Registering the Endpoints 
api.add_resource(TeacherListResource, '/teachers')
api.add_resource(TeacherResource, '/teachers/<int:teacherId>')
```

This schema can be to and returns correctly as:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/teachers \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"name":"brian", "email":"test@dean.com", "connected":"True"}'
{
    "teacherId": 2,
    "email": "test@dean.com",
    "name": "brian",
    "courses": [],
    "connected": true
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!